# .Net Core / IIS web config rewrite rules

Tags: asp.net-core, web-config, url-rewrite-module, asp.net-core-2.0, iis-10

In my situation I have two domains:

```
domain.com
domain1.com
```

where `domain1.com` is the alias of `domain.com`

For `domain1.com` I want to allow only traffic for the urls starting with `api/` and redirect all other traffic to domain.com with 301 status code.

i.e. I want to allow requests like `domain1.com/api/products/list` on the other hand I want to redirect `domain1.com/products/list` to `domain.com`

Can anyone please guide how to achieve this with web.config?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following URL redirect rule should work.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="Domain1">
                    <match url="^(.+)" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{HTTP_URL}" pattern="^/api/(.+)" negate="true" /> 
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Redirect" url="http://domain/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" appendQueryString="true" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Quick explanation.

- We capture the whole incoming URL with `match` pattern for back-reference for the redirect if needed.
- And in `conditions` we negate the API URLs pattern, hence the rule is applied to the URLs *not* containing `/api`.
- The redirect action takes the captured back-reference and appends it to the domain.

Notes.

- You might need to adjust slashes in the rule, I assume there will always be a slash after `/api`.
- Browsers heavily cache permanent redirects, make sure to use a *new* Incognito/Private session each time you modify the rule.